# Method of an object cannot access properties of the object even though everything else can

Tags: javascript

`Game.getRent` cannot read `Game.ownables[0].rent[0]` even though `Game.ownables` is defined 1st!

`Game.ownables` is a list of any objects, that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    rent: [ Numbers... ],
    houses: Number,
    color: Object
  }
]
```

```
Game.getRent = function( ownable ){
  // if the property is a railroad, pay railroad rent, doubling for each railroad owned by the owner
  if( ownable.color.name === "railroad" ){
    return ownable.rent * (2 ** ownable.owner.railroads );
  }
  // if the property is a utility, pay rent based on a die roll
  if( ownable.color.name === "utility" ){
    let die = 1+ Math.floor( Math.random() *6 );
    // 4x die roll for 1 utility, and 10x die roll for both
    return die * ( -2 + ownable.owner.utilities *6 );
  }
  
  // if the proptery is monopolied and we have no houses, the rent is doubled
  if( ownable.color.monopolied && !ownable.houses ){
    return ownable.price[ 0 ] * 2;
  }
  return ownable.price[ ownable.houses ];
};
```

Game is a global variable, so all of its properties should be accessible!

So simple! If we want to get the rent we should just be able to type `Game.getRent()` and relax. However, when **`I`**  type it, I get a nasty `undefined`!

Why?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. A clean code snippet can help a lot with this type of question

Comment: A reproducible example instead of imagining is cooler, but looks like you just forgot to `return`

Comment: Sorry, @KelvinSchoofs, I just didn't want to post a 500 line code snippet. *Actually, it would be more like 100 lines becuase I don't need the entire ownables and baords objects.* I guess I should've just asked on Discord.

Comment: Can you post a minimal self contained example? When I turn your code into that, I get the result that I think you are expecting. Note that I had to add `prices` to your dataset. https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-bnct8e?file=index.js

Comment: I believe the purpose of stackoverflow is to be a catalogue of question / answer about code. With that premise, we would not want to see your exact 500 lines of code, rather a demonstration of the isolated issue written as universally applicable as possible, so that someone else could search for a similar issue and find the answer without repetitive questions. This is also part of the debugging process, to reduce the error to the simplest form to resolve.

Comment: @AlexWayne, thanks for telling my the problem: I asked for `ownable.price[ 0 ]` when price is a `Number`, not an `Array` or `Object`. I meant `rent[ 0 ]`, what a silly mistake!

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value. Like this:

```
var Game = {}
Game.ownables = [ { rent: [343] } ]
Game.getRent = function() {
    return Game.ownables[0].rent[0] // The 'return' keyword tells it to pass that value back from the function
}

console.log(Game.getRent())
```

Without the `return` keyword, nothing is passed back (or returned) from the function, which is why you are getting `undefined`.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting the return on this post -- the problem is more complex than I am making it look.. My actual Game.getRent function has **3 return statements**. I will update the post.

Comment: @Simanalix343 Once the first `return` is called, the function stops. So anything after the first return does not run and is not returned.

Answer (score 0):

You get undefined because you're missing the return keyword. It should be like this:

```
Game.getRent = function() {
  return Game.ownables[0].rent[0];
};
```